# Does a chart control automatically update from an array if the array is bound to the series?

Tags: c#, data-binding, charts

I have seen a number of questions and tutorials about databinding and chart controls but none seem to answer this fairly simple question, if I bind a chart series to an array and update the array with a new set of values will the chart automatically update?

Currently I use the following lines of code to add two lines to a chart every time I update the arrays:

```
Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindY(dPoints1);
Series["Series2"].Points.DataBindY(dPoints2);
```

I thought that once you bound an object to a control the control would automatically change when the object changed but unless I call the DataBindY every time it doesn't.

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The array type doesn't have any events that could trigger a refreshing of the chart, so no this won't do what you're expecting.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to trigger a refresh than calling databind every time?

Comment: @CramerTV: Use a collection that raises update events (such as `BindingList` or `ObservableCollection`, depending on platform)

Comment: @SLaks Will the somewhat-dated .NET charting library know how to interface with those? I think it may only know how to interface with certain types. See the remarks here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd455950.aspx